# Pig Pattern matching

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to find the string "Standard Premium is" in the string "In 2015 the monthly Part B Standard Premium is **$104.90**" but I am unable to do so in Pig .

I am trying with the regex

```
`PlanServiceEng = FILTER PlanService BY language == 'English' and contractid !='' and planid !='' and segmentid !='' and benefit !=''  and (benefit MATCHES '.*Standard Premium is.*');`
```

but when I am trying to find just 'Premium' with the 
below regex it works :

```
PlanServiceEng = FILTER PlanService BY language == 'English' and contractid !='' and planid !='' and segmentid !='' and benefit !=''  and (benefit matches '.*Premium.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the `EqualsIgnoreCase()` function

The `EqualsIgnoreCase()` function is used to compare two strings and verify whether they are equal. If both are equal this function returns the Boolean value true else it returns the value false.

```
PlanServiceEng = FOREACH PlanService GENERATE (language,benefit), EqualsIgnoreCase(benefit, 'Standard Premium is');
```

Or you can try the regex function REGEX_EXTRACT or REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL.

I tried something with `REGEX` ..check if this works for you
Here `%s` would be text you want to match

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE $0,$1,REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL($1,'.*%s.*') ;
```

This statement will add another field where it will have a match and that field is `()`. So in order to get the matched data we will run a filter.

```
filtered = FILTER b BY $2 is not null;
```